# How to stop being notified about partner’s airtags?

Tags: airtag

I got 4 and gave 2 to my gf after deregistering them from my ID. Now I keep getting notified on my iPhone about AirTags traveling with me when we’re together. How can I tell Apple that they belong to my partner who also has access to Apple Home and that I don’t need to be notified?